# In a WAS Liberty connection pool, can I validate connections on borrow?

Tags: datasource, websphere-liberty

We are currently migrating an applications to run on a Liberty server (8.5.5.9).  We have found that connections between the app server and the database are occasionally terminated by the firewall, for being idle for an extended period of time.  When this happens, on the next HTTP request, the application will receive one of these broken connections.

Previously, we had been using Apache Commons DBCP to manage the connection pool.  One of the [configuration parameters in a DBCP conneciton pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html)  is to "testOnBorrow", which prevents the application from being handed one of these bad connections.

Is there such a configuration parameter in a Liberty-managed datasource?

So far, we have configured our datasource like this:

```
    <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/ora" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        <properties.oracle 
          user="example" password="{xor}AbCdEfGh123=" 
          URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@example.com:1521:mydb"
        />
        <connectionManager 
          minPoolSize="3" maxPoolSize="10" maxIdleTime="10m"
          purgePolicy="ValidateAllConnections"
        />
        <jdbcDriver id="oracle-driver" libraryRef="oracle-libs"/>
    </dataSource>
```

The purgePolicy currently is set to validate all connections if one bad one is found (e.g., overnight when all connection have been idle for a long time).  But all this does is prevent multiple bad connection from being sequentially handed to the applications.

One option in the connectionManager would be to set an agedTimout="20m" to automatically remove connections that are old enough to have already been terminated by the firewall.  However, this would also terminate connections that have been recently used (which prevents the firewall from breaking them).

Am I missing something obvious here?
Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest using agedTimeout, since lots of firewalls doesn't care if connection is used or not and just kill connections that are open for long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario I would reccommend using the `maxIdleTime`, which you are already using, but reduce your `minPoolSize` to 0 (or remove it, since the default value is 0).

Per the `maxIdleTime` doc:

> **maxIdleTime**: Amount of time after which an unused or idle connection can be discarded during pool maintenance, if doing so does not reduce the pool below the minimum size.

Since you have your `minPoolSize=3`, the pool maintenence won't kick in if there are only 3 bad connections in the pool for example, because the maintenance thread won't won't take the pool size below the minimum according the the doc.  So setting the `minPoolSize=0` should allow the `maxIdleTime` to clean up all of the bad connections like you would expect in this scenario.

So here is the final configuration that I would suggest for you:

```
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/ora" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <properties.oracle user="example" password="{xor}AbCdEfGh123=" 
                       URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@example.com:1521:mydb"/>
    <connectionManager maxPoolSize="10" maxIdleTime="18m"/>
    <jdbcDriver id="oracle-driver" libraryRef="oracle-libs"/>
</dataSource>
```

The value of `maxIdleTime` assumes that your firewall kills the connections after 20 mins, and to trigger cleanup after 18 mins in order to give the cleanup thread a 2 minute window to clean up the soon-to-be-bad connections.

Comment: I am going to give this a try today to see if it works as advertised.  Thank you for the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

it's an old question but it should be usefull to someone else :
you can use "validationTimeout" property of "dataSource". According to the documentation "when specified, pooled connections are validated before being reused from the connection pool.".
This will not close the connections as soon as they will be cut by the firewall but this will prevent the application to crash beacause of a stale connection.

You can then combine this with purgePolicy="ValidateAllConnections" to revalidate all connections as soon as one is detected as stale.

Reference : https://openliberty.io/docs/21.0.0.1/reference/config/dataSource.html#dataSource